# Winapi c++ trying to get primary monitor's brightness

Tags: c++, winapi

I tried to get the brightness of the primary monitor using the following code:

```
    POINT monitorPoint = { 0, 0 };
    HANDLE monitor = MonitorFromPoint(monitorPoint, MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY);

    DWORD minb, maxb, currb;
    if (GetMonitorBrightness(monitor, &minb, &currb, &maxb) == FALSE) {
        std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
```

But it fails and `GetLastError()` returns `87` which means `Invalid Parameter`.

**EDIT:** I managed to solve this using `EnumDisplayMonitors()` and `GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR()` like this:

```
std::vector<HANDLE> pMonitors;

BOOL CALLBACK MonitorEnumProc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData) {

   DWORD npm;
   GetNumberOfPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor, &npm);
   PHYSICAL_MONITOR *pPhysicalMonitorArray = new PHYSICAL_MONITOR[npm];

   GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor, npm, pPhysicalMonitorArray);

   for (unsigned int j = 0; j < npm; ++j) {
      pMonitors.push_back(pPhysicalMonitorArray[j].hPhysicalMonitor);
   }

   delete pPhysicalMonitorArray;

   return TRUE;
}

// and later inside main simply:
EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, MonitorEnumProc, NULL);

// and when I need to change the brightness:
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pMonitors.size(); ++i) {
   SetMonitorBrightness(pMonitors.at(i), newValue);
}
```

Now I encounter 2 new problems:

1) From `EnumDisplayMonitors()` I get 2 monitor handles since I have 2 monitors. The problem is that only my primary works. Whenever I try to so something with the secondary monitor I get this error:

> 0xC0262582: ERROR_GRAPHICS_I2C_ERROR_TRANSMITTING_DATA

2) After using `SetMonitorBrightness()` for some time it stops working even for the primary monitor and I get the following error:

> 0xC026258D

Comment: Did you validate that `monitor` isn't `NULL` or `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` ?

Comment: Did you call GetMonitorCapabilities to confirm that MC_CAPS_BRIGHTNESS flag is available?

Comment: `MonitorFromPoint()` returns an `HMONITOR`, not a `HANDLE`. Your code would fail to compile if you were compiling with `STRICT` enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing an `HMONITOR` to the function.  However, its documentation states that a handle to a **physical monitor** is required instead, and suggests that you call [`GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd692950.aspx) to obtain it. Indeed, since `MonitorFromPoint()` returns an `HMONITOR` your code would have failed to compile with `STRICT` enabled, a practise that helps root out such mistakes.

You should include error checking for the call to `MonitorFromPoint()`. And the documentation also suggests that you should call [`GetMonitorCapabilities()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd692940.aspx) passing `MC_CAPS_BRIGHTNESS` to make sure the monitor supports brightness requests.

Please refer to the documentation of [`GetMonitorBrightness()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd692939.aspx) for more detail:

Comment: `GetMonitorCapabilities()` returns error `ERROR_GRAPHICS_INVALID_PHYSICAL_MONITOR_HANDLE` which means that my problem is the `HANDLE monitor = MonitorFromPoint(...)` line. Can you give me an example how to use `GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR` to get a handle to the monitor?

Comment: Did you see the example in the [`GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd692950.aspx)? The only difference is that it uses `MonitorFromWindow()` instead of `MonitorFromPoint()`, but that does not really matter in your example.

Comment: @ Remy I finally made it work. Now I got another problem. I use `SetMonitorBrightness()` in a while loop after getting some readings from arduino (serial communication). It works for some minutes, but after some time `SetMonitorBrightness()` fails with error code `3223725453` which is > 15999 and I can't find what it means.